# Can we store a string like "Hello world" on ipfs using web3storage or nft.storage

Tags: json, blockchain, metadata, ipfs, nft

I'm trying to store my encrypted string on nft.storage but I'm getting error that ,

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: source is not async iterable
    at last (index.js:13:1)
    at pack (index.js:14:1)
    at packCar (lib.js:757:1)
    at NFTStorage.encodeBlob (lib.js:472:1)
    at NFTStorage.storeBlob (lib.js:151:1)
    at NFTStorage.storeBlob (lib.js:542:1)
    at storeAsset (Results.jsx:41:1)
    at encryptingData (Results.jsx:71:1)
```

what i had tried is,

```
const metadata = JSON.stringify(encryptedString);
storeAsset(metadata);
```

```
async function storeAsset(metadata) {
    
    const cid= await client.storeBlob(new Blob([metadata]));
    console.log(cid);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
import { Web3Storage } from "web3.storage"; 
    
    const token = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TOKEN; 
      
     function makeStorageClient() { 
       return new Web3Storage({ token }); 
     } 
      
     function makeFileObjects(text) { 
       const obj = { email: text }; 
       const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj)], { type: "application/json" }); 
       const files = [new File([blob], "email.json")]; 
       return files; 
     }
```

For Nft.storage here are the docs: https://nft.storage/docs/client/js/

```js
const { NFTStorage, File, Blob } = require("nft.storage");

const token = process.env.IPFS;

const client = new NFTStorage({ token });

const blob = new Blob([json], { type: "application/json" });
const cid = await client.storeBlob(blob);
console.log(cid);
```